# RedirectToAction() to different folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey Guys I have easy problem, I want to change start page.
In `HomeControllers.cs` I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["LoginId"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login.aspx");
    }
    return View();
}
```

It redirects to: `http://localhost/TutorialCS/Home/Login.aspx`
But I want to get rid off the `/Home`

When in `Global.asax.cs` I change;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

to one without `{Controller}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                         // Route name
            "{action}/{id}",                   // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

It redirects to correct repository, but page dosen't work anymore I suppose this changes a lot of paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String%29) has another overload that accepts controller name as the second parameter:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

So:

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

**Update**:  If you want to redirect to this URL:

```
http://localhost/TutorialCS/Login.aspx
```

You should use [Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx) method:

```
return Redirect("~/TutorialCS/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Now it goes to: localhost/TutorialCS/Account/Login.aspx Which dosen't exist, Putting "" instead of "Account" didn't help either.

Comment: where is Login.aspx located? Is it an action method?

Comment: It's located in main repository \TutorialCS\ like Default.aspx by default, should I move both?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use method call with two parameters: Action name and Controller Name:

```
RedirectToAction("Login", "Account")
```

Comment: Now it goes to: http://localhost/TutorialCS/Account/Login.aspx
Which dosen't exist, Putting "" instead of "Account" didn't help either